# Identify which control my application is using

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a method into my masterpage which populates a value to every label I pass:

```
function FillLabel(field, text) 
{
  $(field).html(text);
}
```

I'll need to make it adaptable to the situation that my `field` receive an html input and to put the text inside this input I need to use `$(field).html(text);`

I need to build an if to identify the type of the `field` and I have no idea how to do that. How can I do this?

Comment: Sometimes an input, sometimes a label... just that

Answer (score 1):

You can check the tag name:

```
var tag = $(field).attr('tagName');
```

*edit* — @Cédric Belin correctly suggests ".is()":

```
var isInput = $(field).is(':input');
```

Much more jQuery-like.

Or check to see if there's a "value" property:

```
if ('value' in $(field)[0]) { ... }
```

So, overall:

```
function FillLabel(field, text) {
  var $field = $(field);
  if ('value' in $field[0])
    $field.val(text);
  else
    $field.html(text);
}
```

You might consider using ".text()" instead of ".html()" but I don't know what your application needs are. You also might consider writing this as a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough details ! According to your code snippet, you seem to talk about JavaScript based on jQuery.

You can test the type of an element with the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method and [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) :

```
var element=$(field);
if(element.is(":input")) element.val(text);
else element.html(text);
```

Comment: Yes clearly ".is()" is better than my ugly "tagName" check :-) I need to make sure I have some coffee in the morning before answering questions.